# Check palindrome in C++/Java

Tags: java, c++, palindrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check string for palindrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138827/check-string-for-palindrome)

Hello experts. I am asked, if it is possible to find whether a string is palidrome of another string in just one line of code in C++/Java.

If yes, then how?

Can any one answer. Thnx for ur view.

Comment: Have you tried reversing one of the strings?

Comment: If you are asked, it is likely for some test or job interview. Isn't it ? If so, what have you done so far and where are you stuck ?

Comment: Surely this makes no sense. It alls depends how long the line is. Both C++ and Java make it easy to put everything on one line for the most part.

Comment: Vote to close for "plz to be sending codes"

Comment: @ John: no its not. Its a question asked in interview to me.        @Joe : I can find reverse and then check with other. But how come in one line in C++? I have no idea

Comment: I think we cannot do it in one line using c++ .. I am not aware of java.

Comment: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Krishna @Stuti in C++ it's just `str == std::string(str.rbegin(), str.rend())` or `equal(str.begin(), str.end(), str.rbegin())`

Comment: nice solution @Cubbi. Since this question explicitly asks for a one-liner I don't agree with that it's a dup...

Comment: @Cubbi: the second is the correct approach. No need to create a reversed copy of the string. To make it even more efficient, you can do: `std::equal( str.begin(), str.begin() + str.size()/2, str.rbegin() )` to reduce the time in half. Single line, linear complexity, no more than one comparison performed on each individual character... what else can you hope for?

Comment: @aioobe @Cubbi: very thnx to you both

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In Java, `String` does not have a `reverse` method. `StringBuilder` has though, so you can still do it in one line:

```
boolean palindrome = str.contentEquals(new StringBuilder(str).reverse());
```

[Ideone.com demo](https://ideone.com/HFme6c)

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the string using reverse and then compare with original string.

```
String str="ABBA"
if(str.COmpareTo(str.reverse()) ==0)
//String is palindrome.
```

Comment: The idea is right, but the code is oh, so wrong.

Comment: This is not a one!!111!! liner.