# String Index Out Of Bound Exception error

Tags: java, string

I'm not really sure why I am getting this error. The code is meant to test palindromes disregarding punctuation.

So here is my code:

```
            char junk;
            String temp = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < txt.length(); i++)
            {
                junk  = txt.charAt(i);
                if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(txt.charAt(jumk)))
                {
                    temp += junk;
                }
            }
            txt = temp;
            left = 0;
            right = txt.length() -1;

            while (txt.charAt(left) == txt.charAt(right) && right > left)
            {
                left++;
                right--;
            }
```

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundException : String index out of range 0
>   at PalindromeTester.main(PalindromeTester.java:35)

and line 35 is as following:

```
    while (txt.charAt(left) == txt.charAt(right) && right > left)
```

Comment: As a side note: I'd replace the first for with: txt.replaceAll("\W", ""); http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum

Comment: You almost had it... this line: Character.isLetterOrDigit(txt.charAt(yP)) is looking for a position in a string, not a character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `yP` is your character *at index* `i`, not an index (as you are using it on the line giving you the error). Change that line to:

```
if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(yP)) { ...
```

EDIT FOR THE NEW PROBLEM:

You don't need a while loop to check if the user entered nothing, since you don't want to do something *repeatedly* in this case (which is what loops are for). Since you only want to do something *once*, i.e. print out how many palindromes they have found, you can just use an `if` statement. The structure would look like this:

```
do {
    get user input

    if they entered the empty string "" {

        print out how many palindromes they have found so far

    } else { // they must have entered text, so check for palindrome

        your normal palindrome checking code goes here

    }

} while (your condition);
```

EDIT 2:

Try changing

```
if (left > right)
```

to

```
if (left >= right)
```

Since if left==right, that means they are both on the median character in an odd-length string (e.g. the 'y' in kayak) which means the string is a palindrome.

Comment: ok actually now it works for saying if it is a palindrome or not but when i just hit enter without putting anything just to get it to say how many palindromes there were  i get another error on line 38 which is: while (txt.charAt(left) ==....... line same error as before

Comment: Yeah. That's because if you don't enter anything, the program doesn't skip to your bottom while loop, it still runs the whole thing. So firstly, you'll try and access txt.charAt(left=0) when there are no characters in txt - that's causing the error. Secondly, programs don't 'remember' values after you quite them and run them again; if you want to know how many palindromes you found, you have to do that *in the same session of the program running* as you actually did the finding.

Comment: I'd talk to you in chat about this if it's easier.

Comment: no i do not mind but yea i just figured that out so how would i get it to still loop the question to them but also have it where the enter a blank it would skip thats what i dont know. Becuase the while loop isn't working until after the whole loop goes through and im not sure how to change that.

Comment: Oh wow my bad, didn't read your code properly! I'll put this in an edit on my answer.

Comment: Ok now it works but after it says You found "" palindromes i get a stringindexoutofboundsexcepton right after wards on another line still with that same while loop as before. while (txt.charAt(left) == .....

Comment: Are you sure that section of code is in an 'else' block? It should be: if empty string { ... } ELSE { all palindrome code }.

Comment: ok it works except there one palindrome that is not working that is supposed to work: Never odd(5,7) or even(4,6) oh and thanks for all the help man; is that going to take a lot to change because i just found out it needed to work with that.

Comment: Yeah, edited with a problem I saw before that might help. And no problem!

Comment: It's also probably worth looking at the answer from this SO question, they are using the same kind of logic as you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138827/check-string-for-palindrome

Comment: Ok its still not working i put "Never odd(5,7) or even(4,6)" into the palindrome tester and it is supposed to work.

Comment: What? That string's not a palindrome. If your program says it's not a palindrome, your program is correct.

Comment: ok i think i may have figured it out thanks for all the help if i have anymore questions i will come to you, since you seem very knowledgeable. Thanks.

Comment: ok i'm not sure if you will respond since this is a little late but im getting an error when i only put punctuation in. Is there a way to fix that and just say its not a palindrome

Comment: Yes, do your loop that filters out all the punctuation *before* you check if the string is empty. I probably should have mentioned that before actually.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work basically i want it when a user enters ,,,,,,,,,,, it says no its not a palindrome but im just getting in out of bound exception.

Comment: i guess i should post a new question maybe.

Comment: You still have the 'while (txt.charAt(left)...' bit at a place in the code where empty strings can get. All code that involves accessing characters in the string MUST be in a section that empty strings can't get to, e.g. if (string is empty) { do something } else { *here is ok to access string chars* }

Comment: ok i got it to work except now it just ends the program because it is thinking the user just entered a blank line and so it says Not a palindrome and then it ends the program.

Comment: If you want something to happen repeatedly, you have to put it in a loop. The if/else structure I mentioned should go inside the larger loop of: while (user has input) { get input; if/else section; }

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(txt.charAt(yP)))
```

is your problem, yP is a char not a reference to a position.

What you probably meant was:

```
 if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(yP))
```

Edit: My comment: 
Well the value of right would be -1 and charAt would require a an integer greater than 0.. so you should check the length of txt and if it's == 0 then display a message saying an actual word is required.

You should stop execution before you get to this line:

```
right = txt.length() -1;
```

This is your fixed code:

```
do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a word, phrase, or sentence (blank line to stop):");
        txt = kb.nextLine();
    }

while (!txt.equals(""));

    txt = txt.toLowerCase();
    char yP;
    String noP = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < txt.length(); i++)
    {
        yP  = txt.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetterOrDigit(txt.charAt(yP)))
        {
            noP += yP;
        }
    }
    txt = noP;

    left = 0;
    right = txt.length() -1;

    while (txt.charAt(left) == txt.charAt(right) && right > left)
    {
        left++;
        right--;
    }

    if (left > right)
    {
        System.out.println("Palindrome");
        cntr++;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Not a palindrome");
    }
```

Comment: No worries, and welcome to stack overflow!  If any of these answers helped you, you should click the checkbox beside their answer to indicate it as the accepted answer.

Comment: ok actually now it works for saying if it is a palindrome or not but when i just hit enter without putting anything i can another error on line 38 which is: while (txt.charAt(left) ==....... line same error as before

Comment: Well the value of right would be -1 and charAt would require a an integer greater than 0..  so you should check the length of txt and if it's == 0 then display a message saying an actual word is required.

Comment: yea what im meaning is in the do while loop i want it to somehow skip it it  if they enter a blank line and tell them how many palindromes there are. I tried to do it with the do while loop but since it is asking them in the loop the while doesn't work until after.

Comment: See my edited post, and you'll see the closing of the while loop is what gets you.

Comment: yea that works except i need to have it tell them if its a palindrome or not right after they enter it.