# Checking a string for a palindrome (java) (rookie status)

Tags: java, logic, palindrome

I am trying to check to see if, entered a string, that the string is a palindrome

if it is display something positive
if not... something negative (invalid)

I am currently getting the answer invalid both times (no matter what is entered)
i'm not quite sure if there is a problem with the for loops or the boolean statement.

```
    //ACTION FROM BUTTON PERFORMED HERE
private void ButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    //creating variables
    String myString = textField1.getText();
    int stringLength = myString.length();
    char arrayOne[] = new char[stringLength];
    char arrayTwo[] = new char[stringLength];
    boolean palindrome = false;

    //for loop to setup ARRAY ONE
    for(int i = 0; i < stringLength-1; i++){
        arrayOne[i] = myString.charAt(i);
    }

    //for loop to setup ARRAY TWO
    for(int i = stringLength-1; stringLength-1 > i; i--){
        arrayTwo[i] = myString.charAt(i);
    }

    //for loop checking if array indexes are equivalent in value (char)
    for(int i = 0; i < stringLength-1; i++){
        if(arrayOne[i] != arrayTwo[i]){
            palindrome = false;
        }
        else{
            palindrome = true;
        }
    }

    //assigning text to the text boxes based on boolean palindrome
    if(palindrome == true){
        textField2.setText("Valid");
    }
    if(palindrome ==false){
        textField2.setText("Invalid");
    }
}
```

}

i think i commented it descently

Comment: either use a debugger or add debug code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138827/check-string-for-palindrome?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
for(int i = stringLength-1; stringLength-1 > i; i--)
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < stringLength-1; i++)
```

and change

```
for(int i = stringLength-1; i-1 > 0; i--)
```

to

```
for(int i = stringLength-1; i-1 >= 0; i--)
```

**EDIT:**

That was a debugging fest!!

Here is a working code:

```
    String myString = textField1.getText();
    int stringLength = myString.length();
    char arrayOne[] = new char[stringLength];
    char arrayTwo[] = new char[stringLength];
    boolean palindrome = true;
    //for loop to setup ARRAY ONE
    for(int i = 0; i <= stringLength-1; i++){
        arrayOne[i] = myString.charAt(i);
    }

    //for loop to setup ARRAY TWO
    for(int i = stringLength-1, pos = 0; i >= 0; i--, pos++){
        arrayTwo[pos] = myString.charAt(i);
    }

    //for loop checking if array indexes are equivalent in value (char)
    for(int i = 0; i <= stringLength-1; i++){
        if(arrayOne[i] != arrayTwo[i]){
            palindrome = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    //assigning text to the text boxes based on boolean palindrome
    if(palindrome == true){
          textField2.setText("Valid");
    }
    else{
        textField2.setText("Invalid");
    }
```

Comment: If `stringLength` is greater than 1, this will be infinite loop, because `stringLength` is never changed inside the loop.

Comment: using this gives me an error "string index out of range"
if you changed the ">i" to ">0"

Comment: @LeeHurlbert Right.  Not infinite, because it will end up with exception :)

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov any suggestions? ^-^ :O

Comment: @LeeHurlbert There were some errors... I have corrected them.. now it's fine.

Comment: @Aditi You should check your code before posting.

Comment: @ExtremeCoders Yes I should.

Comment: @LeeHurlbert Also, there were many more bugs in the code which have been fixed now. See the edit.

Comment: @aditi sir, you're a saint. thank you so much!
i know i had a lotta logic bugs and out of limits but i really did (unfortunately) try to understand it
now i've got it!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the other answers about your error, but I think a more concise solution would be

```
boolean isPalindrome(String myString) {    
    int n = myString.length;
    for( int i = 0; i < n/2; i++ )
        if (myString.charAt(i) != myString.charAt(n-i-1)) return false;
    return true;    
}
```

Your code would now be

```
private void ButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    String myString = textField1.getText();     
    textField2.setText( isPalindrome(myString) ? "Valid" : "Invalid" );
}
```

Comment: i definitely like this - but it doesn't have both of the arrays, should i call this seperately

Comment: You don't need arrays at all. I suggest not even using them when you can access the characters of the string one by one anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This loop copies all characters except the last one which probably is not what you wanted:

```
//for loop to setup ARRAY ONE
for(int i = 0; i < stringLength-1; i++){
    arrayOne[i] = myString.charAt(i);
}
```

It should probably be fixed like this:

```
//for loop to setup ARRAY ONE
for(int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
{
    arrayOne [i] = myString.charAt (i);
}
```

Body of this loop:

```
//for loop to setup ARRAY TWO
for (int i = stringLength-1; stringLength-1 > i; i--)
{
    arrayTwo [i] = myString.charAt (i);
}
```

is never executed, because initial value of `i`: `stringLength - 1` does not satisfy loop condition: `stringLength - 1 > i`.

You should probably change it to be:

```
// For loop to setup ARRAY TWO
for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
{
    arrayTwo [i] = myString.charAt (stringLength - i - 1);
}
```

Also, after this loop:

```
// for loop checking if array indexes are equivalent in value (char)
for (int i = 0; i < stringLength-1; i++)
{
    if (arrayOne [i] != arrayTwo [i])
    {
        palindrome = false;
    }
    else
    {
        palindrome = true;
    }
}
```

variable `palindrome` will contain result of last comparison only, so if all characters except the last ones were different but last characters were equal, `palindrome` will be `true` which is probably not what you wanted.  Probably you should change the code like this:

```
palindrome = true;
for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
{
    if (arrayOne [i] != arrayTwo [i])
    {
        palindrome = false;
    }
}
```

Note that I also changed `stringLength - 1` to `stringLength`, otherwise you were ignoring last characters.

Comment: I see - then if i were to change the second part "stringLegnth-1>i" to "i>0" would it satisfy the condition or make it forever true

Answer (score 1):

```
//for loop to setup ARRAY TWO
for(int i = stringLength-1; stringLength-1 > i; i--){
    arrayTwo[i] = myString.charAt(i);
}
```

This falls over after the first iteration.

You need to change it to something like:

```
//for loop to setup ARRAY TWO
for(int i = stringLength-1; i > 0; i--){
    arrayTwo[i] = myString.charAt(i);
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Worked perfectly and i realized my mistake

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to test for a palindrome in java

```
String str = "Able was I ere I saw Elba"
boolean palindrome = str.equalsIgnoreCase(new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString());
```

Yep, that's it.

Comment: I thank you for this ^_^ however, {and i know weird} i'm actually trying to write the method "check reverse" thanks tho!

Comment: Should probably also trim() it

Comment: easiest, yes, most efficient, no

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "akaq";
    boolean b = false;
    for (int i = 0, j = s.length() - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
            b = true;
            continue;
        } else {
            b = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (b)
        System.out.println("Palindrome");
    else
        System.out.println("Not Palindrome");
}
```

Try something like this instead of 2-3 for loops.

Answer (score 0):

Change the first for loop from stringLength-1 to just stringLength because you are using < and not <=

Change the second for loop to

```
if(int i = stringLength-1; i>=0; i--)
```

Also, set palindrome to true by default and remove the

```
else{
    palindrome = true;
}
```

part because now if the first and last characters of the loop are the same, but not the middle, it will return true.

EDIT: Also the third for loop should be stringLength and not stringLength-1 because you are using < and not <=

Comment: do you mean for(int i = stringLength-1; i>=0; i++)

Comment: No, because then i would increase forever and never be less than 0.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to copy everything into arrays. String is basically an array itself. You can access the individual characters with `charAt()`.

Also there is no need to loop the entire length of the String since equality is associative.

So simply use :

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() / 2; i++) {                  // only until halfway
        if (s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(s.length() - i - 1)) {      // accessing characters of String directly
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

One last remark : if the String's length is odd, you don't need to check the middle chracter. So in the code above the diision by