# Palindrome Program using Recursion

Tags: java, palindrome

This is currently what I have for my Palindrome program for my computer science class. I have it pretty much working, except whenever a word is a palindrome, it is an infinite loop. I know I have to insert a number base case, but I do not how to do that...I'm really having trouble understanding recursion. Help is appreciated.

```
public class PalindromeTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        String str, another = "y";
        int left, right;

        while (another.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {

            System.out.println("Enter a potential palindrome:");
            str = scan.next();

            left = 0;
            right = str.length() - 1;

            tester(str, left, right);

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Test another palindrome (y/n)?");
            another = scan.next();

        }
    }

    public static void tester (String str, int left, int right)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);


        while (str.charAt(left) == str.charAt(right) && left < right)
        {
            System.out.println(str);

            tester( str, left + 1, right -1);

        }
        if (left < right)
        {
            System.out.println("That string is NOT a palindrome.");
        }

        else 
        {

            System.out.println("That string IS a palindrome.");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you use a debugger and debug your code?

Comment: Read [Check string for palindrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138827/check-string-for-palindrome)

Comment: Your while loop is never ending because you don't change left and right in the loop. Either use a loop, or use recursion but don't try to use both.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a while loop. With recursion, this is done implicitly.

You have to *split* the algorithm in small parts.

[] represents left, {} represents right.

```
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 {1} -->Level 0
1 [2] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 {2} 1 -->Level 1
1 2 [3] 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 {3} 2 1 -->Level 2
1 2 3 [4] 5 6 7 8 9 0 9 8 7 6 5 {4} 3 2 1 -->Level 3
1 2 3 4 [5] 6 7 8 9 0 9 8 7 6 {5} 4 3 2 1 -->Level 4
1 2 3 4 5 [6] 7 8 9 0 9 8 7 {6} 5 4 3 2 1 -->Level 5
1 2 3 4 5 6 [7] 8 9 0 9 8 {7} 6 5 4 3 2 1 -->Level 6
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 [8] 9 0 9 {8} 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 -->Level 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 [9] 0 {9} 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 -->Level 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 {[0]} 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 -->Level 9
```

So, `tester` will continue until:

1. We've reached the middle of the word.
2. The word is not a palindrome

Example of case 2:

```
[1] 2 3 A 5 6 7 8 9 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 {1} 
1 [2] 3 A 5 6 7 8 9 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 {2} 1 
1 2 [3] A 5 6 7 8 9 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 {3} 2 1 
1 2 3 [A] 5 6 7 8 9 0 9 8 7 6 5 {4} 3 2 1 --> !!!
```

I thought this method would be very helpful for the understanding of how is this recursion working

```
public static String positions(String word, int l, int r) {
        char[] a = word.toCharArray();
        String s = "";
        // [letter] if left, {} if right, [{}] if both 
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (l == i && r == i) {
                s += "{[" + a[i] + "]}";
            } else if (l == i) {
                s += "[" + a[i] + "]";
            } else if (r == i) {
                s += "{" + a[i] + "}";
            } else {
                s += a[i];
            }
            s+=" ";
        }
        return s;

    }
```

And finally, the `tester` method.

```
public static boolean tester(String str, int left, int right) {

        System.out.println(positions(str, left, right) +" tester(str, "+left +", "+right+")");
        if (left>=right) // case 1
            return true; // that's ok, we've reached the middle
            // the middle was not reached yet.
            // is the condition satisfied?
        if (str.charAt(left) == str.charAt(right)) {
            // yes. So, lets do it again, with the parameters changed
            return tester(str, left + 1, right - 1);

        } 
        //the condition was not satisfied. Let's get out of here.
        else {

            return false;
        }

    }
```

Some outputs:

```
Enter a potential palindrome:
1234567890987654321
[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 {1}  tester(str, 0, 18)
1 [2] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 {2} 1  tester(str, 1, 17)
1 2 [3] 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 9 8 7 6 5 4 {3} 2 1  tester(str, 2, 16)
1 2 3 [4] 5 6 7 8 9 0 9 8 7 6 5 {4} 3 2 1  tester(str, 3, 15)
1 2 3 4 [5] 6 7 8 9 0 9 8 7 6 {5} 4 3 2 1  tester(str, 4, 14)
1 2 3 4 5 [6] 7 8 9 0 9 8 7 {6} 5 4 3 2 1  tester(str, 5, 13)
1 2 3 4 5 6 [7] 8 9 0 9 8 {7} 6 5 4 3 2 1  tester(str, 6, 12)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 [8] 9 0 9 {8} 7 6 5 4 3 2 1  tester(str, 7, 11)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 [9] 0 {9} 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1  tester(str, 8, 10)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 {[0]} 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1  tester(str, 9, 9)
true

Test another palindrome (y/n)?
y
Enter a potential palindrome:
12345A678654321
[1] 2 3 4 5 A 6 7 8 6 5 4 3 2 {1}  tester(str, 0, 14)
1 [2] 3 4 5 A 6 7 8 6 5 4 3 {2} 1  tester(str, 1, 13)
1 2 [3] 4 5 A 6 7 8 6 5 4 {3} 2 1  tester(str, 2, 12)
1 2 3 [4] 5 A 6 7 8 6 5 {4} 3 2 1  tester(str, 3, 11)
1 2 3 4 [5] A 6 7 8 6 {5} 4 3 2 1  tester(str, 4, 10)
1 2 3 4 5 [A] 6 7 8 {6} 5 4 3 2 1  tester(str, 5, 9)
false

Test another palindrome (y/n)?
```

In the `main` method,

```
System.out.println(tester(str, left, right));
```

In order to see the `true/false` output

Answer (score 0):

Since your are using recursion (in its basic purposes mostly used to eliminate loops), isn't your `while` loop inside the `tester()` method supposed to be an `if`?

```
public static void tester (String str, int left, int right)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    if (str.charAt(left) == str.charAt(right) && left < right)
    {
        System.out.println(str);

        tester( str, left + 1, right -1);

    }
    else if (left < right)
    {
        System.out.println("That string is NOT a palindrome.");
    }

    else 
    {
        System.out.println("That string IS a palindrome.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake

Answer (score -1):

I modified your `tester()` method and replaced your `while` with an `if` and moved your second `if` clause.

```
public static void tester(String str, int left, int right) {
        if (str.charAt(left) == str.charAt(right) && left < right) {
            tester(str, left + 1, right - 1);
        } else {
            if (left < right) {
                System.out.println("That string is NOT a palindrome.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("That string IS a palindrome.");
            }
        }
    }
```