# how to check if string is palindrome of another string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to check if a string that is passed in to a function is a palindrome of the second string that is passed in. Google defines a palindrome to be a word that is the same spelled forwards or backwards.

```
def palindrome(strA, strB):
  if (strA == strB and strA[::1] == strB):
    print "true"
  else:
    print "false"


if __name__ == '__main__':
  palindrome("sirap", "paris")
```

In the code above, I am attempting to check if the given string is equal to the second string both forwards and backwards yet the test i give it in main returns false. Any ideas on what im missing?

Comment: `strA[::1]` is the same as `strA`. You want `strA[::-1]`

Comment: What is a string that is palindrome of another one? As far as I know a string is palindrome if it's the same string backwards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check-string-for-palindrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138827/check-string-for-palindrome/)

Answer (score 4):

You check if `'sirap'` is the same as `'paris'` as well as checking if reversed `'sirap'` is the same as `'paris'`.  You just have too many things in your `if`:

```
if strA[::-1] == strB:
    print "true"
else:
    print "false"
```

What you had *would* work if you passed in a palindrome as well as its reverse, the same thing.  For example, `palindrome("stats", "stats")` would print `"true"`, but I don't think that's what you had in mind.  You will also notice that I used `strA[::-1]` instead of `strA[::1]`.  That is because `strA[::1]` starts at the beginning and goes to the end, but you want to go backwards, so you should use `-1`.

You could even do it in one line:

```
print ("false", "true")[str[::-1] == strB]
```

Comment: Talking about removing if? Maybe - `return strA[::-1] == strB`

Comment: That is not quite the same thing.  Currently, it prints instead of returns.  You did make me think of something, though... See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar test using the "100 projects" to learn python (useful for learning any language)

You could do something like this, and just run the script. For this I just made some changes to the original palindrome script I wrote.

```
print "This will check if its a palindrome"
inputstring = raw_input("String1: ")
inputstring2 = raw_input("String2: ")
inputstring = inputstring.lower()
inputstring2 = inputstring.lower()
revstring = inputstring[::-1] #Reverses the string

if revstring == inputstring2:
    print "Yes: " + revstring
else:
    print "No: " + revstring
```

Comment: You don't need the parenthesis around `inputstring[::-1]`.