# StringBuilder and equals to compare original and reversed string

Tags: java

The program checks if the reverse of string and original string are same and for getting reverse of string,i am using stringbuilder in java and to compare the revese,eual of java but output is not correct.If original string and reverse string are same,output yes else output NO .

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;
public class Stringuse {
    private static Scanner in;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s=in.next();
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(s);
        sb.reverse().toString();
        System.out.println(sb);
        boolean ans=sb.equals(s);
        System.out.println(ans);
        if(ans==true)
            System.out.println("Yes");
        else
            System.out.println("No");
    }
}
```

Comment: `StringBuilder`s are not going to equal `String`s no matter what.  You'll have to use `sb.toString().equals(s)`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman can you give a correct version of your code in comments

Comment: Also, `if (ans == true)` is redundant. `if (ans)` is enough

Comment: Better way of doing it without creating a new string or using StringBuilder for that matter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138827/check-string-for-palindrome

Comment: @Goaler444 * provided the string consists entirely of single-char codepoints.

Answer (score 4):

You probably just need to change it to

```
boolean ans = sb.toString().equals(s);
```

since only `String`s equal other `String`s; a `StringBuilder` cannot be equal to a `String`.

...though you can also write `sb.reverse()` instead of `sb.reverse().toString()`, and `if (ans)` instead of `if (ans == true)`.

Comment: StringBuilder cannot be equal to String, and also to other StringBuilder with same content, because StringBuilder doesnt implement equals method

Answer (score 1):

I  just made few changes as suggested in comments and it works fine now.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  in = new Scanner(System.in);
  String s=in.next();
  StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(s);
  boolean ans= sb.reverse().toString().equals(s);
  if(ans==true)
    System.out.println("Yes");
  else
    System.out.println("No");
}
```