# How to check if a number is a palindrome?

Tags: java, palindrome

I wrote a piece of code for a class homework. However I thought it was quite long! Is there a more optimized way to do this?

```
String text = input.readLine();
int num = (text.length())/2;
double letter = (double)(text.length())/2;
String s1 = text.substring(0,num);
int u1 = Integer.parseInt(s1);      

if (letter%1==0) {           
    StringBuffer s2 = new StringBuffer(text.substring(num));
    s2 = s2.reverse();
    String t2 = s2.toString();
    int u2 = Integer.parseInt(t2);
    if (u1==u2) {
        System.out.println("Palindrome");
    } else {
        System.out.println("FAIL");
    }
} else {
    StringBuffer s2 = new StringBuffer(text.substring(num+1));
    s2= s2.reverse();
    String t2 = s2.toString();
    int u2 = Integer.parseInt(t2);
    if (u1==u2) {
        System.out.println("Palindrom");
    }else {
        System.out.println("FAIL");
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check string for palindrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138827/check-string-for-palindrome)

Comment: Take a look at my answer. I have shown two methods to check for palindrome. And don't forget to mark it as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it it helped you by clicking on the hollow tick next to the answer :) Accepting gives you reputation too. If you don't accept any answer, people may be reluctant to answer your future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert the string back to number in order to compare them. You can use string's `equals()` method to check if they are equal. Check this out (with necessary changes this will work for any string though, not just numbers).

```
int num = 12300321;
String numString = String.valueOf(num);
String reverseNumString = new StringBuilder(numString).reverse().toString();

if(numString.equals(reverseNumString)) {
    System.out.println(num + " is a Palindrome!");
}
else {
    System.out.println(num + " is not a Palindrome!");
}
```

Output:

```
12300321 is a Palindrome!
```

**Alternate method** (using only number manipulation; will work for integers only)

```
int num = 12300321;
int numCopy = num;
int reverseNumInt = 0;

while(numCopy != 0) {
    reverseNumInt = reverseNumInt * 10 + numCopy % 10;
    numCopy /= 10;
}
if(reverseNumInt == num) {
    System.out.println(num + " is a Palindrome!");
}
else {
    System.out.println(num + " is not a Palindrome!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, but handling the numbers digit by digit is simpler and more readable:

```
public static boolean isPalindromic(String num) {
    for(int i = 0, len = num.length() ; i < len/2 ; i++) {
        if(num.charAt(i) != num.charAt(num.charAt(len-i-1))) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```