# check the Strings if they are palindrome

Tags: java, boolean, palindrome

I am suppose to use Boolean to check if the string is palindrome. I'm getting an error, not sure what I am doing wrong. My program already has 3 strings previously imputed by a user. Thank you, I am also using java

```
 public  boolean isPalindrome(String word1, String word2, String word3){

 int word1Length = word1.length();
 int word2Length = word2.length();
 int word3Length = word3.length();

 for (int i = 0; i < word1Length / 2; i++)
{
    if (word1.charAt(i) != word1.charAt(word1Length – 1 – i))
    {
        return false;
 }
}
return isPalindrome(word1);
}

for (int i = 0; i < word2Length / 2; i++)
{
if (word2.charAt(i) != word2.charAt(word2Length – 1 – i))
    {
        return false;
    }
 }
 return isPalindrome(word2);
}
 for (int i = 0; i < word3Length / 2; i++)
{
if (word3.charAt(i) != word3.charAt(word3Length – 1 – i))
{
return false;
}
}
return isPalindrome(word3);
}

  // my output should be this
 if (isPalindrome(word1)) {
  System.out.println(word1 + " is a palindrome!");
  }
  if (isPalindrome(word2)) {
  System.out.println(word2 + " is a palindrome!");
   }
  if (isPalindrome(word3)) {
  System.out.println(word3 + " is a palindrome!");
  }
```

Comment: Have a look at this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138827/check-string-for-palindrome

Comment: You have all the pieces there you just have some syntax errors im sure. Just make 1 method with the following signature `public boolean isPalindrome(String word)`. Get rid of your method `isPalindrome(String, String, String)`. Make sure your method is inside a class and not another method.

Comment: I see that they just use 1 string, but my program has 3? not sure what to do

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can improve your question by formatting your code for readability and to eliminate scrolling. You might even discover your own problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a method for it like this:

First you build a new String and than you check if it is equal.

```
private static boolean test(String word) {
    String newWord = new String();      
    //first build a new String reversed from original
    for (int i = word.length() -1; i >= 0; i--) {           
        newWord += word.charAt(i);
    }       
    //check if it is equal and return
    if(word.equals(newWord))
        return true;        
    return false;       
}

//You can call it several times
test("malam"); //sure it's true
test("hello"); //sure it's false
test("bob"); //sure its true
```

Comment: This works, but I am confused why does it only need 1 string?

Comment: it's only because the algorithm, you don't need your function to input 3 parameter, if you want check 3 string, just call this function 3 times with different parameter

Comment: It "receives" only one par

Comment: Sorry, you could start here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html