# How to check if a number is palindrome in Java?

Tags: java

I am new in Java and I need to complete this program to check if an integer is palindrome. Please help.

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    System.out.println("Please enter an integer : ");
    int integer = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

    if(isPalindrome(integer)){
        System.out.println(integer + " is a palindrome");
    }else{
        System.out.println(integer + " is not a palindrome");
    }       

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check string for palindrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138827/check-string-for-palindrome)

Comment: what is the problem with this code?

Comment: where is `isPalindrome()` defined?

Comment: This code has already been completed and a simple search would have found it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(int integer) {
    int palindrome = integer;
    int reverse = 0;

    // Compute the reverse
    while (palindrome != 0) {
        int remainder = palindrome % 10;
        reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
        palindrome = palindrome / 10;
    }

    // The integer is palindrome if integer and reverse are equal
    return integer == reverse; // Improved by Peter Lawrey

}
```

Advanced solution: (Provided by Shadov)

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(int integer) {
    String intStr = String.valueOf(integer); 
    return intStr.equals(new StringBuilder(intStr).reverse().toString());
}
```

Reference: http://www.java67.com/2012/09/palindrome-java-program-to-check-number.html#ixzz4emXfiD7V

Please do not just put up question without your work next time.

Comment: avoid answering off topic questions.. also how is this any different from the other one?

Comment: why not `return integer == reverse;`?

Comment: Nice catch, Peter.

Comment: @PeterLawrey because it's simply picked up from http://www.java67.com/2012/09/palindrome-java-program-to-check-number.html#ixzz4emXfiD7V :)

Comment: @SrishtiRanjan I agree, but just because you copied someone else's work doesn't mean you shouldn't try to improve it. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes, you are right. Nice one. :)

Comment: @PeterLawrey spot on! :D

Comment: Just for future generations: 
`String.valueOf(number).equals(new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(number)).reverse().toString());`

Comment: @Shadov Thanks for the improvement.

Comment: @SkyLuke Oh, you added that to your answer, then you can extract `String.valueOf(number)` into variable so it's not called twice for the same argument :)

Comment: @Shadov Ok, sure :)

Comment: how do you deal with the integer overflow issue without writing code to explicitly dealing with it?

Comment: The implementation only using int does not handle negative numbers.

Comment: if ( x < 0  )    {
        return false;
    }

Comment: String operations takes about double the time of integer operations.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
    int palindrome = number; // copied number into variable
    int reverse = 0;

    while (palindrome != 0) {
        int remainder = palindrome % 10;
        reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
        palindrome = palindrome / 10;
    }

    // if original and reverse of number is equal means
    // number is palindrome in Java
    if (number == reverse) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Source: http://www.java67.com/2012/09/palindrome-java-program-to-check-number.html#ixzz4emXfiD7V

But you need to clearly not put up homework questions here.

Comment: Please do not answer homework questions

Comment: How you guys (@sky and @Srishti) managed to answer on same time :D