# User validation testing in Java while loop

Tags: java, loops, validation

> I am making one of my first java projects checking if a user input word (no numbers or symbols) is a palindrome.  I used the method outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4139065/10421526 for the logic.  The code works per-request but I am having trouble re-prompting the user after invalid input as it seems to "block" the ability of my code to accept valid input, printing my "retry" message.  I have also tried the do while version but I ended up with formatting errors.  I think the way I define my stringOut variable is giving me trouble but Im not sure how to change that without making a duplicate as eclipse says. Here is the closest I could get after dozens of tries going in circles:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PalindromTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("Input word to test: ");
        String stringIn = in.nextLine();
        String stringOut = new StringBuilder(stringIn).reverse().toString(); 

        while (!stringIn.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input, try again.");
            in.next(); //stops infinite error loop
        }

        if ((stringIn.equalsIgnoreCase(stringOut))) {
            System.out.println("Palindrome detected");
            System.out.println("You entered: " + stringIn);
            System.out.println("Your string reversed is: " + stringOut);

}       else {
            System.out.println("Not a palindrome");
}

    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you never alter the value of `stringIn`. In your loop, you'd need to do `stringIn = in.next();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `in.next();` in while loop to                 `stringIn= in.next();` and after while loop add             `stringOut = new StringBuilder(stringIn).reverse().toString();` .

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


            System.out.println("Input word to test: ");
            String stringIn = in.nextLine();
            String stringOut = new StringBuilder(stringIn).reverse().toString(); 

            while (!stringIn.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input, try again.");
                stringIn= in.next(); //stops infinite error loop
            }
            stringOut = new StringBuilder(stringIn).reverse().toString();
            if ((stringIn.equalsIgnoreCase(stringOut))) {
                System.out.println("Palindrome detected");
                System.out.println("You entered: " + stringIn);
                System.out.println("Your string reversed is: " + stringOut);

    }       else {
                System.out.println("Not a palindrome");
    }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A very good use-case to use `do-while` loop. You use this loop when you have to make sure that your statements are executed at least once. And the subsequent execution is executed only if it matches a condition. In this case, that condition would be *validating your input*.

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String prompt = "Input word to test: ";

    String stringIn;

    do {
        System.out.println(prompt);
        stringIn = in.nextLine();
        prompt = "Invalid input, try again.";
    }
    while (stringIn.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"));
```

If the input is `non-numeric` the while condition would be `true` and will make this loop run again, hence asking for new input. if the input is `numeric` the while condition will be `false` hence exit the while loop and will give you user input in `stringIn` variable.