# Efficient way to determine whether an input string is a palindrome or not

Tags: java, string, optimization, palindrome

I recently wrote this short method to determine whether a string is a palindrome. I was wondering what I could do to make it more efficient, surely I'm missing simple built-in functions that can speed up the calculation.

Thank you all for your help!

```
boolean checkPalindrome(String inputString) {

    ArrayList<Character> arrFront = new ArrayList<Character>();
    ArrayList<Character> arrBack = new ArrayList<Character>();

    for(int i=0; i<inputString.length()-1; i++) {
        arrFront.add(inputString.charAt(i));
    }

    for(int i=inputString.length()-1; i>0; i--) {
        arrBack.add(inputString.charAt(i));
    }

    StringBuilder builder1 = new StringBuilder(arrFront.size());
    for (Character c : arrFront) {
        builder1.append(c);
    }
    String front = builder1.toString();

    StringBuilder builder2 = new StringBuilder(arrBack.size());
    for (Character c : arrBack) {
        builder2.append(c);
    }
    String back = builder2.toString();

    return(front.equals(back));
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `speed up`? time complexity, or less code?

Comment: You mean like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4139065/8534008)? Note that this is less code, but is [not very efficient](http://componentsprogramming.com/palindromes/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Code Review SE.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Yes the simple loop solution (`for (int i = 0; i < n/2; ++i) {
        if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(n-i-1)) return false;
    }`) is a better choice if you're concerned about efficiency

Comment: @GBlodgett Making use of `str.length()` will also speed up things! Returning early will safe some time.

Comment: @Glains That's what `n` represents in the code. It is resolved to a variable to avoid the `length()` method being called twice every iteration of the loop

Answer (score 5):

In terms of efficiency, it is not always about built-in functions and using libraries (although in many cases they are the best choice). But sometimes a simple loop like this could be the most simple and efficient way:

```
private boolean checkPalindrome(String inputString) {
    for(int i = 0, j = inputString.length() - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        if(inputString.charAt(i) != inputString.charAt(j)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can refer to @FernandoPelliccioni article [Check string for palindrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138827/check-string-for-palindrome). He did very thorough analysis for this solution.

for the simple solution:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
    return str.equals(new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString());
}
```

in terms of efficiency :

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
    int n = str.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < n/2; ++i) {
       if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(n-i-1)) return false;
    }
    return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler way.

```
public boolean checkPalindrome(String str) {
    int len = inputString.length()/2;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++) {
        if(str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(str.length()-1-i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

When the length of str is `N`. The time complexity is `O(N/2)`.
Note: you don't need to check the middle character when the length of str is odd because it is itself.

For example,

In `ssstsss`, you don't need to check `t`.

And since `len` is int. It can't express `decimal part`. It automatically drops.
`len` of `ssstsss`is `3` because it is `7/2 = 3.5` and drops `0.5`.

Even if its length is even, it will work. For example, `abccba`. The length is `6`. And `len` is `3`. When the length is even number, you must check even the two characters in the middle, which is `cc`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use the default `StringBuilder`. 
This class got a nice function wich could be usefull.
It is called `reverse()`. It does what it says, it reverses the String wich is parsed into the `StringBuilder`. With this it is pretty easy to just check if the given String equals the reversed.

For example you could do:

```
public boolean isPallindrome(String input){
    StringBuilder reversed = new StringBuilder(input);
    reversed.reverse();
    /*
     * Just replace equals with equalsIgnoreCase
     * to ignore the case
     */
    return(reversed.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(input));
}
```

The given code just creates a `StringBuilder` instance and directly appends the input.
It then reverses the `StringBuilder` and checks if the input equals the reversed String.