# Is this Java palindrome solution efficient? It doesn't use string or char methods

Tags: java, palindrome

Here's the solution I saw:

```
package com.philippemoisan;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isPalindrome(-212));
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(int number)  {
        int reverse  = 0;
        int initNumber = number;
        while (number != 0)  {
            int lastDigit = number % 10;
            reverse = reverse * 10;
            reverse +=lastDigit;
            number/=10;
        }
        if (initNumber == reverse)  {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I know there are palindrome solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138827/check-string-for-palindrome) but I am not that far in my Java course yet.
So, I just want to know if the solution I posted here is efficient, or would it a lot better to use the solutions from the thread link I provided.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution on the linked answer is more efficient, because if the word is not palindrom, it will not iterate through the entire number/word.

The solution you provided loops through the entire number/word even when the first step can detect that the first and the last digit/char are not identical.

Answer (score 0):

The link that u provided is for string palindrome and the program u have posted is for a number palindrome. Palindrome concept is same and that's where similarity ends.

The time and space complexity of a string palindrome is entirely different from an integer palindrome.

Hope that helps.best wishes for ur journey in Java