# error: variable or field 'Palindrome' declared void in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14

I'm getting this error hence I am new to c++ I could not understand
please help me!!!

I am writing a palindrome code
This is the code given below:.............

I am basically here using some extra concepts not doing in-direct fashion.
if anyone can post the correct code he/she is most welcome...

```
//palindrome
#include <cstring>  //or use #include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

void Palindrom(string& );

void Palindrome(string& word)// same as (const string& word)
{ 
    int n = word.length();
    string word2;
    char reverse[n]; 

 for(int i = 0; i <=n; i++){
        word[i]=tolower(word[i]);
    }
    word2=word; //now both are small

    for(int i = n-1; i >=0; i--){
        reverse[n-1-i]=word2[i];
        cout<<reverse[n-1-i];
    } 


    for(int i =0; i >n; i++){    //printing reversed 
        cout<< " Reverse:  "<<reverse[i]<<endl;
    } 


    // word is ok and word2 gets reversed  

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++){ 
       if(word[i]==reverse[i])
       {
           cout<<"\nit is palandrome ";

       }
    cout<<"\nit is not a palindrome ";
    }
}

int main()
{  string k="YuUuy";
   void Palindrome(k);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check string for palindrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138827/check-string-for-palindrome)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct syntax for calling a function is `Palindrome(k);` without the void.

Few remarks:

- Get a [good c++
  book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).
- `// same as (const string& word)` is not true.
- You did not include `<string>` header.
- It's good practice to use `std::size_t` for indices, but beware of `unsigned>=0` condition being always true.
- `char reverse[n];` is wrong, `n` must be a compile-time constant, VLA are not part of the C++ standard.

Answer (score 2):

Function calls should not have return type. Change `void Palindrome(k);` in main() function to `Palindrome(k);`

While declaring array, the expression should have constant value. So you can't use `char reverse[n];`. Change it to `char *reverse = new char[n];` and deallocate it using `delete[] reverse;` after you are done using it.

I would recommend you to use smart pointer. You should also take a look at `std::string` instead of using stream of `char`.