# I am checking for pallindrome string..Why does this always print yes

Tags: java, string

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
  String A=sc.next();
  StringBuffer a1 = new StringBuffer();
  a1.append(A);
  System.out.println(a1.equals(a1.reverse())?"Yes":"No");
}
```

Comment: Does this answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138827/check-string-for-palindrome

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check string for palindrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138827/check-string-for-palindrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will always return `yes` as `a1.reverse()` returns original `StringBuffer` object which is same as `a1`. If you want to compare string, you have to generate string from stringbuffer object:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String A=sc.next();
    StringBuffer a1 = new StringBuffer();
    a1.append(A);
    System.out.println(a1.toString().equals(a1.reverse().toString())?"Yes":"No");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes by converting it into a string first you would be able to compare them .
Otherwise you would be comparing there address(StringBuffer address),which is same is case of both.