# How can I print the special character but still I can compare it if its a palindrome or not

Tags: java, palindrome

```
import java.util.*;
public class Fin4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter a word to check if it is a palindrome: ");
        String word = in.nextLine();
        
        word = word.replaceAll("[{}!@#$%^&.,' ]", "");
        word = word.substring(0);
        String reverse = "";
        for(int i=word.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
            reverse+=word.charAt(i);
            
        if(word.equalsIgnoreCase(reverse))
            System.out.print(word + " is a palindrome.");
        else
            System.out.print(word + " is not a palindrome.");
    }
}
```

For example
Enter a word to check if it is a palindrome: Madam, I'm adam
The output should be -> Madam, I'm adam is a palindrome
but my output is -> MadamImadam is a palindrome

Comment: `String original = word;` <- this saves a copy (run this BEFORE `.replaceAll`, of course), then you can print that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check string for palindrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138827/check-string-for-palindrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the copy of the original word in a variable ( say copyWord) and print that variable in the print statements.

The reason why the original string is not getting printed is because you are modifying it and storing the updated word( in word.replaceAll())

```
public class Fin4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a word to check if it is a palindrome: ");
        String word = in.nextLine();
        String copyWord = word;
        word = word.replaceAll("[{}!@#$%^&.,' ]", "");
        word = word.substring(0);
        String reverse = "";
        for (int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            reverse += word.charAt(i);

        if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(reverse))
            System.out.print(copyWord + " is a palindrome.");
        else
            System.out.print(copyWord + " is not a palindrome.");
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
Enter a word to check if it is a palindrome: Madam, I'm adam
Madam, I'm adam is a palindrome.
```