# Checking if the given String is Palindrome or not, using Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, if-statement

I have taken an input from the reader as a String I want to check whether the given input String is Palindrome or not, by using Array.

First, I took the String as "RacecaR" I stored that String in "Bytes Array" using "getBytes()" string class methods, and then I tried to use "for-loop" to get "Reverse Bytes Array." After that, I wanted to store that reverse bytes array into a Character Array that way I can easily check whether the given string is palindrome or not, but I am facing a problem while storing the reversed bytes array into the Character Array. Can anyone solve this problem?
I know I can easily do this using the "String Buffer" class "reverse" method, but I want to check using the "String" class.
Below is the code:

```
public class ClassA {
    
    void meth1()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the string to be checked to see if it's a palindrome.");
        String s = sc.next();
        byte rev[] = s.getBytes();
        for(int i = rev.length-1;i>=0;i--) 
            System.out.print(i);
        //char[] charArray = ?? //How to store bytesArray into charArray?
        
            //String res =  new String(char[]); 
            
        
            if(s.equals(res))
                System.out.println("It is a palendrome");
            else
                System.out.println("It is not a palendrome");
            
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClassA().meth1();
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on your encoding,  charakters can have more than one byte size. I recommend you to not do this task with a reversed byte Array. Use the method.toCharArray() for getting a char array out of your String.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create a reversed array, you can modify existed one.

```java
public static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
    char[] buf = str.toCharArray();

    // reverse array
    for (int i = 0, j = str.length() - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
        swap(buf, i, j);

    return str.equals(new String(buf));
}

private static void swap(char[] arr, int i, int j) {
    char ch = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = ch;
}
```

But, if you look up further, you will see, that `String` already contains an array inside. So to check that string is palindrome you do not even create a new array or string or modify an array.

```java
public static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
    for (int i = 0, j = str.length() - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
        if (str.charAt(i) != str.charAt(j))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

- Time complexity: `O(n)`
- Space complexity: `O(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your encoding, characters can have more than one byte size.

I recommend you to not do this task with a reversed byte Array.

Use the method .toCharArray() for getting a char array out of your String.

String s = "hello";
char[] chars = s.toCharArray();

Comment: There is also a _char_ _[IntStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)_ available via the _[String#chars](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#chars())_ method.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to extract the individual bytes. You can use the `toCharArray` method to get a `char[]` having the individual characters of the input string. Then you can reverse it and build a new string out of it.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the string to be checked to see if it's a palindrome.");
String s = sc.next();
char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
int n = arr.length;

// Construct reversed char[]
char[] rev = new char[n];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    rev[i] = arr[n - i - 1];
}
String reversedString = new String(rev);

if (s.equals(reversedString)) {
    System.out.println("It is a palindrome");
}
else {
    System.out.println("It is not a palindrome");
}
```

Note 1: There are better ways to solve this (with O(1) space). This answer helps OP to solve their problem by following a similar approach as theirs.

You can learn more about other solutions in this question - [Check string for palindrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138827/check-string-for-palindrome)